# XLPagerTabstrip . how can i update bar title from another tab

Tags: swift, xlpagertabstrip

Xcode 10.1 XLPagerTabStrip

I have 4 tab

tab1 . tab2. tab3. tab4

case1.
if current index is tab1

```
 if let pagerTabStrip = self.parent as? ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {

   pagerTabStrip.buttonBarView.reloadData()

}
```

this code is work perfectly

case2.
if current index is tab3 but i want to update title of tab1

```
if let pagerTabStrip = self.parent as? ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {

   pagerTabStrip.buttonBarView.reloadData()

}
```

this code didn't work .

how can i update bar title from another tab

Comment: You could try posting a notification or using delegation.

Comment: @quant24  if current active tab is tab1  code work perpectly . but current active tab is 2 or 3 or 4..   code didn't work .    only work tab1 is activated